# how to change view controller width size programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to make a `viewcontroller` manually without using pod following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl_Re_KLhcY&t=141s

[image]

but the **sideMenuVC** (the green one) has width that set accurately, I mean, the sideMenuVC should be 80% of the size of **MainMenuVC**. so if I change from iPhone 5s to iPhoneX, the `autolayout` still look perfect. But this is what I get

[image]

the sideMenuVC should be 80% only, but it looks full size on iPhone 5s

in sideMenuVC `viewDidLoad` I want to set something like this

```
class SideMenuVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sideMenu: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sideMenu.frame.width = self.view.frame.width / 2
       }
}
```

but it doesn't work since it is get only property

so I want to change the width in here
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would optimally want to achieve your desired output is keep the view controller's width as is, but add a normal `view` inside with the following constraints

1. Leading to `superview` with a constant value of 0
2. Top to `superview` with a constant value of 0
3. Bottom to `superview` with a constant value of 0
4. Width equal to `superview` with a multiplier value of 4:5

You also need to set the background color of the `UIViewController`'s default `view` property to `.clear`.

Finally, set the presentation style of that newly created `UIViewController` to `Over Current Context`.

> When presenting a view controller using the UIModalPresentationFullScreen style, UIKit normally removes the views of the underlying view controller after the transition animations finish. You can prevent the removal of those views by specifying the UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext style instead. You might use that style when the presented view controller has transparent areas that let underlying content show through.